# Keyboard lights on my laptop MSI

Tags: keyboard, laptop, msi, keyboard-backlight

I have an MSI laptop and I would like to know if there is a way to install software to change the colors of the keyboard lights. Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which version of Ubuntu do you have installed? (Edit the information into your question)

Answer (score 0):

I found this command line application which may or may not work depending on your keyboard.

The installation will be

`sudo apt-get update` and then

`sudo apt install msi-keyboard`

[image: synaptic_screenshot]